# Warning Message Popup

Tags: jquery, warnings, message

Here I have one web page like create. suddenly if i click on other tab need to show warining message like are sure want to leave

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something.';

confirmationMessage += 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

(e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
return confirmationMessage;

});</script>
```

But my problem if i fill all fields and submit i got e you want to leave for above code. i Need to get warning message only if i click other page or other tab

Please help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

beforeunload event will be invoked no matter how the page unloads whether it is a button click, tab or any link. To check it on specific elements you should use onClick events of those elements.